SharePoint 2019 Search indexing error after SSL certificate renewal
After recent SSL certificate renewal (using self-signed Server certificate, the same as the expired one), SharePoint Server Search failed to crawl web app using the new certificate. Other web apps don't have any problem.
The troubled sites are accessible via browser, but with the following message: Your connection to this site isn't secure
Craw history error message: An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser. ( Error from SharePoint site: WebException TrustFailure The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.;
The search service account can access all sites content. Any idea how to address the issue? Thanks
